# jdk not being picked up by vista, but the path is correct

Tags: windows-vista, java, jdk

Here is my path :

```
C:\Program Files\ICW>path
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files\Mi
crosoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;F:\downloads\a
gntctrl.win_ia32-TPTP-4.7.1a\bin; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;
```

and javac is not recognized :

```
C:\Program Files\ICW>javac
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So I cd to directory to prove it works:

```
C:\Program Files\ICW>cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin"
```

and it works

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin>javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
```

BUT the Java app(?) in control panel (which I have never seen/used before) shows the jre is installed, and everytime I try and reference the jdk it just overwrites it, see below.  I am embarrased to admit I have over 10 years experience as a java developer ... which btw is unaffected, eclipse/maven are picking up jdk correctly. Its just the windows command prompt.
[image]

Comment: Is this just a cut/paste error on your post?  `...\Tools\binn\C:\Program Files\Tortoi...`

Comment: Is `F:` always there?  I think it's possible that searches won't go past an absent drive, etc.

Comment: @DanH THANKYOU. I think that typo must have caused the rest of path to fail.

Comment: Paths on Windoze are a PITA, because they're so hard to edit (without error) in the tiny windows provided.  Stupid design.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the space before `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;` in your `PATH` as well as add a `;` after this entry `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\`

I'm also guessing that `binn` is a typo?